# Rails 3 appending object to an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a view where I am trying to display all the objects in an array. The objects are tickets.

```
<tbody>
    <% @tickets.each do |ticket| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= ticket.ticket_number %></td>
            <td><%= ticket.title %></td>
            <td><%= ticket.product_name %></td>
            <td><%= truncate(ticket.description) %></td>
            <td><%= ticket.status %></td>
            <td><%= link_to "Show", users_ticket_path(ticket) %>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

My controller is finding all Users that have the same 'reseller_id' as the current User.
So say I have 3 Users all under the same Reseller. The 3 Users all have the same 'reseller_id'
Here is my controller that doesn't work.

```
def index
  if admin_user?
    @test = "HELLO"
    all_users = User.find_all_by_reseller_id(current_user.reseller_id)
    all_users.each do |u|
      @tickets = u.tickets
    end
  #@tickets = @tickets.paginate(page: params[:page])
  else
    @test = "WORLD"
    @tickets = current_user.tickets.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
end
```

This saves a blank array. 
How do I make an array with all the ticket objects?

Thanks

Comment: Would anyone know why this works in development mode and not in production mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently `@tickets` is equal to tickets of last user found. Use something like this

```
def index
  @tickets = []
  if admin_user?
    @test = "HELLO"
    all_users = User.find_all_by_reseller_id(current_user.reseller_id)
    all_users.each do |u|
      @tickets += u.tickets
    end
  #@tickets = @tickets.paginate(page: params[:page])
  else
    @test = "WORLD"
    @tickets = current_user.tickets.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
end
```

Comment: I did not know I could use +=  awesome

Comment: Do you know why this works in development mode but now in production mode?

Comment: what error are you getting in production? If you get empty `@tickets` in production while non-empty `@tickets` in development then it could be due to lack of data in production db.

Comment: I do not get an error. The array is displaying only the current_user and not the other User's tickets in production. All three users have tickets.

Comment: seems like the production app has not been restarted to use the new code.

Comment: I restarted the apache server, is there something else I need to restart?

Comment: the index method returns current user tickets if `!admin_user?`, Is that condition true in production server request?

Comment: Yes the condition is true. I placed a puts "blah" in each part of the index method and they show in development mode but none show in production mode. Is it possible in production a different controller is being used?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37700/discussion-between-tihom-and-dddd)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it in one line

```
def index
  if admin_user?
    @test = "HELLO"
    @tickets = Ticket.where("user_id IN (?)", User.find_all_by_reseller_id(current_user.reseller_id).map(&:id))
    @tickets = @tickets.paginate(page: params[:page])
  else
    @test = "WORLD"
    @tickets = current_user.tickets.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
end
```